# cannot run a video party in a community page

Tags: facebook-pages, facebook-videos

I have two similar pages, I've created them as community pages.

I'm publishing live videos on both pages, and when I finish the live session I share them in their respective pages.

On the first page, I'm able to run a video party in the page: when I create a post I have the video party option.

On the second page, however, I havent' the video party option when creating a post, and even if I start from a video and use the "run a video party" menu option, facebook tells me that it cannot start it.

I suppose that I have the same setting in both pages, but surely it's not so, since the behaviour is different...

What setting could affect the possibility to start a video party?

Comment: Have you read the [How do I start a watch party on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/help/1681245065258554)? Most likely you will find your answer there. If you do, let me know and will turn my comment to an answer so others can benefit as well. BTW, are you the admin or editor on both pages?

Comment: I had read it, it doesn't solve